# jQuery text change smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML and jQuery code to warn users about using the 'remember me' check box as follows:

in HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember"> Remember me
<span id="remember_feedback"></span>
```

In Script:

```
$('#remember').change(function(){
     if(this.checked){
          $('#remember_feedback').text('(Don\'t use on a public computer)');
     }else{
          $('#remember_feedback').text('');
     }
});
```

It works fine but I would like the text to smoothly / slowly changes as i've seen on some sites not pops in and out as it does now, is it possible without using plugins?

Comment: Are you meaning fading in/out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
$('#remember').change(function(){
     if(this.checked){
          $('#remember_feedback').hide().text('(Don\'t use on a public computer)').fadeIn('slow');
     }else{
          $('#remember_feedback').fadeOut('slow');
     }
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pFd44/)

Comment: Hello answer is Correct +1 from me , but its Fiddle ,not Fillde :)

Comment: wow! didn't expect this to work. +1 for shorter answer. Can u explain how .hide().text() makes the text show instead of hidden?

Comment: first "hide()" hides "remember_feedback" element then "text("")" sets a text after that "fadeIn()" shows feedback text with easing effect!

Comment: Suppose it comes down to personal preference, but if the element is only ever going to contain that static text I prefer it be in the HTML and hidden. Prevents extra chaining in the jQuery too.

Comment: yea, bt it's just a easy way to fix without touching other html or css files :) . and that way it'll be easy to change text if the text is dynamic. depends on requirement of user who posted this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the desired text to the html:

```
<span id="remember_feedback">(Don't use on a public computer)</span>
```

... then in css, hide it by default:

```css
#remember_feedback {
    display:none;
}
```

... then just use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` in js:

```
$('#remember').change(function(){
      if(this.checked){
          $('#remember_feedback').fadeIn();
      }else{
          $('#remember_feedback').fadeOut();
      }
 });
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nw3DJ/)** you can play with.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the answers below, you can also use jQuery's `.fadeToggle()` (including the addition of the message into the span in the HTML);

```
var fadeTime = 500; // Time (ms) for fade animation

$('#remember').change(function(){    
    $('#remember_feedback').fadeToggle(fadeTime);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kjqS/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Add the text initially to the remember_feedback span and set it to be hidden by default using the html5 [hidden](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp) attribute:

```
<span id="remember_feedback" hidden >Don't use on a public computer</span>
```

Then just show and hide it in the js:

```
$('#remember').change(function()
{
      if(this.checked)
      {
          // Parameter is number of milliseconds to fade the element
          $('#remember_feedback').fadeIn(1000); 
      }
      else
      {
          $('#remember_feedback').fadeOut(1000);
      }
});
```

Comment: for better browser support, hiding `remember_feedback` is more desirable, i find...

Comment: it will be hidden using the "hidden" attribute from html5